# Two towns separated by wall: humans one side, monsters other

Tags: story-identification, comics, books

I'm not sure if this is a book or comic book, but it's about a human city separated by a massive wall from a "monster" city (giant beasts, liches, goblins, witches, etc).

It's futuristic and fantasy at the same time, I think it's another planet.

Once a year, 5-6 teens are sent as ambassadors/emissaries/sacrifices, and I believe they never come back.

This year the city leaders have a plan to have the kids steal some orb of power that's on the monster side.

I think stealing it generates some huge cataclysm on the entire planet.

Comment: Where did you read this? And when? What language was it in?

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE Jheurf! Feel free to take the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand our site better. This really seems like an interesting book (upvoted) Hope you'll get your answer soon.